# Run jar file with arguments without having to use command line

Tags: java

I am using `Alpn-boot` to add support for **HTTP.2** requests using **OkHttp**. In order for that to work i always have to launch my compiled jar file through the command line and specify the path of `alpn-boot.jar` file with a `<-Xbootclasspath>` argument :

`java -jar -Xbootclasspath/p:<path_to_alpn-boot.jar> <path_to_myjar.jar>`

Is there anyway to avoid this, and make the jar run with the **-Xbootclasspath** argument specified by default?

**Edit:** I thought about using a batch file to do this, but is there no other native way?

Comment: By scripting it, you could replace the whole command line with a single command.

Comment: I thought about using a batch file, but i'm trying to see if there is any other way to avoid even that. Going to update my question.

Comment: How you launch a program directly form the desktop depends entirely on the OS and window manager.  It is not possible to answer this question unless you tell us what OS you're on.

Comment: @JimGarrison
I'm using windows, a portable solution would be nice though if available.

Comment: Assuming your goal is to launch the program from a desktop shortcut, just put the necessary command into a shortcut.  But that's so obvious that I am not sure I understand what you're asking.  If you mean to launch the program in background at boot time, use the "Startup" folder or other autorun mechanism.  You can also set it up as a Windows Service (lots of reference material on the web for this).

Comment: @JimGarrison
Oh, i don't know why this didn't come to my mind! I'll take that if it's my best option here. Nicer that a batch file for my case. Thanks!

Comment: @JimGarrison
A problem i come across, is that the command line runs and is attached with the jar window now. If i close the cmd window the jar app also closes. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Use the `javaw` command to run without a console window.

Answer (score 0):

Batch file is convenient and standard enough. Unless you have specific reason not to use batch file, batch file would do it

Comment: I kinda have a feel, a batch file would seem suspicious to the end user. Wrapping it in an exe, or as Jim suggested, creating a shortcut and passing it the arguments, would be the better option for my case.